# I created a simple ball game. Now I try to make the ball moving faster.... does anyone have an idea?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsarray

the ball i want to move faster  is the *enemy;

i want that *enemy move faster after 20 seconds without touching the ball.
The *player ball is the ball that you can control. In this game You aren't allowed to touch 
the enemy ball.

I want the enemy ball to become faster every 20 seconds.. I was thinking about something with an array loop ....

thank you for helping

---

### .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIButton *startButton;
    NSTimer *randomMain;

    CGPoint pos; 
    IBOutlet UIImageView *enemy;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *player;

    int MainInt;
    IBOutlet UILabel *seconds;


    IBOutlet UILabel *lastTime;
    IBOutlet UILabel *theTime;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSTimer *numro;

- (IBAction)start;
@end
```

---

### .m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize numro;

- (IBAction)start {
    [startButton setHidden:YES];
    randomMain = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(0.03)
      target:self selector: @selector(onTimer) userInfo:(nil) repeats:YES];
    numro = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0)
      target:self selector:@selector(countup) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    MainInt = 0;
    [lastTime setHidden:YES];
    [theTime setHidden:YES];
}

-(void)countup {
    MainInt += 1;
    seconds.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", MainInt];

// I TRIED IT WITH "IF"  BUT IT I DONT WANT TO WRITE THIS FOR EVERY 20 SECONDS

    if (MainInt == 20) {
        randomMain = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(0.002)
      target:self selector: @selector(checkCollision) userInfo:(nil) repeats:YES];
    }
     /*   if (MainInt == 40) {
        randomMain = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(0.01)
      target:self selector: @selector(onTimer) userInfo:(nil) repeats:YES];
    }*/
}

-(void)onTimer{
    [self checkCollision];
    enemy.center = CGPointMake(enemy.center.x+pos.x,enemy.center.y+pos.y);
    if (enemy.center.x > 320 || enemy.center.x < 0)
        pos.x = -pos.x;
    if (enemy.center.y > 480 || enemy.center.y < 0)
        pos.y = -pos.y;
}

- (void)checkCollision {
    if( CGRectIntersectsRect(player.frame,enemy.frame))
    {
        [randomMain invalidate];
      [startButton setHidden:NO];

        CGRect frame = [player frame];
        frame.origin.x = 137.0f;
        frame.origin.y = 326.0;
        [player setFrame: frame];

        CGRect frame2 = [enemy frame];
        frame2.origin.x = 137.0f;
        frame2.origin.y = 20.0;
        [enemy setFrame: frame2];

  UIAlertView *alert =[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"AAA"
        message: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"BBB"] delegate:nil 
                 cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        MainInt = 0 ;
        [numro invalidate];
        [lastTime setHidden:NO];
        [theTime setHidden:NO];
        theTime.text = seconds.text;
    }
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *myTouch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    player.center = [myTouch locationInView:self.view]; //player ball
}

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [lastTime setHidden:YES];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // X Speed Y Speed
    //I tried to do anything with the X and Y speed ... but it didn't work
    pos = CGPointMake(5.0,4.0);
}

@end
```

Comment: Did you try to read your own code after you had posted it?

Comment: @H2CO3 I just suggested an edit, should be fixed any second

Comment: sorry! I wasn't finished yet...  i will do it better

Comment: thats the whole code with a more specific description

Comment: Sorry for mistakes I'm from Germany ^^(16 years old)

Comment: oh!! You've disturbed the code formatting again!! @NSAddict, fix it once again..

Comment: I'm really sorry, but i wasn't finished yet.. and i've no idea ...  this is my second post...

Comment: ok... no problem... not discouraging you... someone experienced here can correct the formatting.

Comment: @everyone Captain is on the way :D

Comment: Don't post whole bunch of code. Just show the code related to your question. Now your question is about the speed of enemy ball, only post code that is related to moving enemy ball and that controls the speed of enemy ball.

Comment: but I didn't know if you are able to understand it then.. I try to do it better in my next post. Thank you.

Comment: there are two ways to speed up the enemy ball... 1st is NSTimer* randomMain  in the scheduledTimeWithTimeInterval  and the 2nd is CGPoint *pos   X and Y speed

Comment: How much do you want to increase speed every 20 seconds? Is there any formula for that?

Comment: I want to make it a bit faster to make the game harder.. in the scheduledTimeWithTimeInterval I would make it from 0.03 to 0.02 or 0.01    and in the CGPoint   +2 X  and +2 Y ..

Comment: but not both at once     either... or ..

Comment: I tried many methods.. but everything was to complicated.. too much to write..  if.. if.. if .. if..  And I thought.. there must be an easier way....

Comment: @EndritÇallaki... +1 to encourage you for asking good questions! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// Now, from the 20th second, the ball becomes faster every second :S

```
-(void)countup {

MainInt += 1;
seconds.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", MainInt];


if(MainInt % 20 == 0) {    //True every 20th second

    int speedUpCount=MainInt/20;
    float interval=1.0 - (speedUpCount/1000.0);

    [randomMain invalidate];   //Must stop the previous timer
    randomMain = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:interval target:self selector: @selector(start) userInfo:(nil) repeats:YES];
```

Answer (score 2):

Change `if` block in your `countup` method as follows...

```
if(MainInt % 20 == 0) {    //True every 20th second

   int speedUpCount=MainInt/20;
   float interval=1.0-(speedUpCount/10.0);

   [randomMain invalidate];   //Must stop the previous timer

   randomMain = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:interval target:self selector: @selector(checkCollision) userInfo:(nil) repeats:YES];
}
```

Hope this would help solving your problem.

Comment: Thank you... thats really good.. there's one Problem..  If I do this [randomMain invalidate]; the enemyballs stops after 20 seconds..

Comment: enemyball* not enemyball(s)  theres only one :-)

Comment: stops for a while or remains stopped?

Comment: mmmm the ball don't want to become faster ... but i don't give up thank you for helping :-) if you have an idea why that don't work, let me know it ;-)

Comment: the ball is still at the same speed.. :-(

Comment: The timer is continuing but the ball stops when the timer == 20